# Take text from Text area

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I have this html code -

```
<form method="post" style="width:100%; margin-bottom:40px;" >
                <textarea id="wall_post" style="width:100%;; margin-left:-4px; margin-right:auto; resize:none;" rows="4"></textarea>
                <input id="wallPost" type="submit" value="Post" method="post" style="float:right; font-size:65%;" />
                <div id="vectors" style="display:inline; float:left; margin-right:20px;">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="sms" value = "SMS" method = "post"/><label for="sms" style="font-size:65%;">SMS</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="email" value = "Email" method = "post"/><label for="email" style="font-size:65%;">Email</label>

                </div>  
            </form>
```

As you can see there are a few buttons. I'd like to have it so that when say the checkbox with value SMS is clicked, the stuff in the textarea is passed to a django view. I know I can pass stuff into django using a jquery ajax post with the relevant url conf, but how do I do so on the request of the user? (in pseudocode - if user clicks post, give django function text area text)

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Why do you have to change whether or not your textarea is being submitted to django?

It's not much data. Why not always submit it and check in your view if the SMS checkbox is checked?
If checked: do something with textarea data. If not: don't.

Note: you're missing the `name` attribute on each of your inputs.

```
def my_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST.get('sms'):
            # do something with text area data since SMS was checked
            print request.POST.get('my_textarea')

        # process form as usual.
```

If you want to change whether or not django reads your data, you could potentially dynamically add or remove the textarea's `name` attribute with javascript, but this is riskier and more work than the above solution.

### update - the html to work with above code.

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <textarea name="my_textarea"></textarea>
    <input type="checkbox" name="sms" />
</form>
```

Comment: wait, so where am I getting the text area data here, also, I'm getting a CSRF error- does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: To solve the csrf error you should add `{% csrf_token %}` right after the form opening tag. Also make sure you have `'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'` and `'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfResponseMiddleware'` on your settings.py `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`

Comment: re the CSRF error, read VascoP's comment. The text area data is submitted when you submit an html form element with child inputs with name attributes. Let me update with an example HTML form.